# MySQL LIMIT using SELECT COUNT(*) as value within SELECT

Tags: mysql

Trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE
start_time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 6 HOUR)
LIMIT
(
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM events WHERE
start_time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 6 HOUR)
AND
start_time < NOW()
)+100
ORDER BY start_time ASC;
```

Not workIng for me though.

Comment: Trying to limit the number of results based on the number of events between 6 hours ago and now plus the 100 I'm displaying after now.

Comment: looks like you need to be using a `union`.  you want all the events of the last 6 hours, plus the next 100 events, is that correct?

Comment: Like how? Not seeing how.

Comment: Im not sure, but I think mysql does not support subquery as an argument to LIMIT clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM events e
WHERE e.start_time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 HOUR) AND
      e.start_time < NOW()
UNION ALL
(SELECT e.*
 FROM events e
 WHERE e.start_time >= NOW()
 ORDER BY e.start_time
 LIMIT 100
)
ORDER BY start_time;
```

You cannot use a subquery for the `limit` parameters.

Comment: What is this `e` you're using?

Comment: The `e` is an *alias* assigned to the table reference `events`. The alias is assigned following the table name in the `FROM` clause. We use that alias to *qualify* column references. By adding the alias and a dot before the column name. Here e.g. `e.*` means all the columns in the `events` table. (Better practice is to qualify all column references, e.g. `WHERE e.start_time` . But this is only required when the column reference would be ambiguous without it. In this simple example, it's not apparent how the alias helps us much. But in more complex queries, table aliases are indispensable.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a limit variable and use that.

```
SET @limit= (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM events WHERE
        start_time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 6 HOUR)
    AND
        start_time < NOW()
   )+100;

SELECT * FROM events WHERE
    start_time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 6 HOUR)
LIMIT @limit
ORDER BY start_time ASC;
```

Comment: Hello, I am trying to do something like this but i am getting error `syntax error @limit` this is my query 'SET @limit= (
    SELECT COUNT(dispID) FROM dispanser
   );
   
select * from counter limit @limit;'

Comment: Same Problem for me.